# Is there a more efficient way to join a big table that this?

Tags: mysql, join

Consider the following. On an e-commerce site I have a `sales_order` table and a `subscription` table.

The `sales_order` table has well over 1 million rows and about 25+ columns. The columns I'm interested in are:

```
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| entity_id | base_subtotal | subscription_id | + many more
+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

In my `subscriptions` table I have the following

```
+-----------+----------+----------+
| entity_id | interval | quantity | + more
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

So basically the subscription created orders in the order table which and the `sales_order.subscription_id` is used to reference.

I want to retrieve the SUM value of the `base_subtotal` for each subscription.

```
+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------+
| entity_id | interval | quantity |  total_revenue  |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------+
```

SO I have the following...

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `orderTable`.`base_subtotal` AS `revenue`, SUM(orderTable.base_subtotal) AS `total_revenue` 
FROM `subscriptions` AS `main_table` 
LEFT JOIN `sales_order` AS `orderTable` ON main_table.entity_id = orderTable.subscription_id 
GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`;
```

This gets the correct data but takes AGES on the live server with the million+ rows.

**There is no index on the subscription_id in the sales_order table!**

So two questions:
 - 1. Is there a more efficient way to write this query?
 - 2. Is it 'safe' to add an index to a huge table with like this without bringing it down? This would need to be done to a live db so I'm very cautious about it.

Thanks

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Add an index on `(subscription_id, base_subtotal)`

Comment: And please, do **NOT** `SELECT` the `orderTable`.`base_subtotal` column (the SUM is fine) when you group by other columns.

Comment: The speed of adding the index depends on what version of MySQL you have.  But you _must_ do it, so _do it_.